# .NET C# retrieving data from Firebase

Tags: c#, .net, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm facing some problems while retrieving data to my .net app from database hosted on Firebase. While debugging I noticed that `response` contains `[{"Description":"desccc","Id":2},{"Description":"asdfasdf","Id":1}]` and this is the only record in my db so I think for this moment everything is ok. Unfortunatelly, when trying to put this data into `result` it throws error like this:

> {System.MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for this object.   at System.Activator.CreateInstanceT   at RestSharp.Deserializers.JsonDeserializer.Deserialize[T](IRestResponse response)   at Rate_Your_Game.Controllers.GameController.GetGames() in PATH/Rate Your Game\Controllers\GameController.cs:line 49}

```
[HttpGet("[action]")]
public async Task<Game[]> GetGames()
{
    try
    {
        client = new FireSharp.FirebaseClient(config);
        FirebaseResponse response = await client.GetTaskAsync("Games/");
        Game[] result = response.ResultAs<Game[]>();
        return result;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw e;
    }
}
```

This is my Game class

```
public class Game
    {
        public Game() {}

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Description{ get; set; }    
        
    }
```

Comment: Why null is coming in the result?

Comment: The `Game` class needs to have a default constructor without parameters to be deserialized.

Comment: @VimalCK null is coming because first record in my firebase has key "1" and it probably thinks that it could be started from 0. When I manually add a record with key 0, null disappeared

Answer (score 1):

The `Game` class needs to have parameterless constructor.

```
public class Game {
     public Game(){
     }

     ....
}
```

Comment: My class looks like this - empty parametrless constructor and uderneath I have fields: Id and Description. The error still occurs